# Incorrect number of dimensions - parallel R computation

Tags: r, tm, snow

I have an issue when using the tm package and parallel computation in R and I'm not sure if I'm doing something silly or if it is a bug.

I created a small reproducible example:

```
# Load the libraries
library(tm)
library(snow)

# Create a Document Term Matrix
test_sentence = c("this is a test", "this is another test")
test_corpus = VCorpus(VectorSource(test_sentence))
test_TM = DocumentTermMatrix(test_corpus)

# Define a simple function that returns the matrix for the i-th document
test_function = function(i, TM){ TM[i, ] }
```

If I run a simple lapply using this example I get what expected without any problem:

```
# This returns the expected list containing the rows of the Matrix
res1 = lapply(1:2, test_function, test_TM)
```

But if I run it in parallel I get the error:

*first error: incorrect number of dimensions*

```
# This should return the same thing of the lapply above but instead it stops with an error
cl = makeCluster(2)
res2 = parLapply(cl, 1:2, test_function, test_TM)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the different nodes do not automatically have the `tm` package loaded. Loading the package is necessary, however, because it defines the `[` method for the the relevant object class.

The code below does the following:

1. start a cluster
2. load the `tm` package in all nodes
3. export all objects to all nodes
4. run the function
5. stop the cluster

---

```
cl <- makeCluster(rep("localhost",2), type="SOCK")
clusterEvalQ(cl, library(tm))
clusterExport(cl, list=ls())
res <- parLapply(cl, as.list(1:2), test_function, test_TM)
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: you are totally right.. what a silly mistake. I assumed that once the matrix was calculated then there was no need anymore for the library without thinking that the [ method was inside the package. Thanks a lot!